# One user shows as Contact instead of Mailbox, after migration to Office365

Tags: migration, microsoft-office-365, active-directory

We recently did a cutover migration from an on-premises Exchange 2010 server to Office 365. We've set up dirsync to synchronize accounts and passwords from our local AD. All mailboxes and shared mailboxes appear to be working fine, except one.

One account shows op in Exchange Online as a contact instead of a mailbox. I want this account to be a proper mailbox user, with IMAP login credentials etc., and am not sure why I didn't see any difference in AD between this account and others that are working correctly.

When I sent a test mail from my own account to this contact it was bounced with the error:

```
Remote Server returned '550 5.7.12 RESOLVER.RST.SenderAuthenticated; Delivery restriction check failed as sender not authenticated'
```

Any idea what's different about this account? Where should I look? How do I turn it into a proper mailbox?

Comment: So was there a mailbox on-premise before, and now there's not one in either? Is the contact type in EO listed as "Mail Contact" or "Mail User"? It's hard to say where to look without knowing a bit more about what has happened to the mailbox, how it was migrated etc.

Comment: Do you still have access to the old on-prem AD and Exchange? If so can you let us know how the user in question is setup within them?